# rails controller descending order get the first element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is wrong with this statement

```
@lastloc = Location.all(:customer_id == resource.id , :order => 'created_at DESC').first
if (@lastloc.longitude != params[:customer][:longitude] && @lastloc.latitude != params[:customer][:latitude])
  ...
end
```

What i am trying to do is to grab all Location with a certain id, then order then with the latest one then verify if different value then i proceed else do nothing

Comment: replace `all` with `where`.

Comment: do you mean `:customer_id == resource.id`? that will evaluate to a boolean (always false, unless resource.id is the symbol :customer_id)

Comment: resource id is from devise, it gives me customer id, 1,2,3... i am not sure but is my if statement the proper ruby way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Location.where("customer_id = ?", resource.id).order('created_at DESC')
```

The IF condition looks ok, you can modify the "&&" for "and", but that is a question of style only.

If you are not certain about the record being retrieved from the database you can start a rails console and check the record, the command is:

rails c -s

This will start a rails console in sandbox mode (all your modifications will roll back after you quit the console).

Comment: I changed it for clarity, my real question is if the data are the same will my if execute what inside or not, cause i dont want it to execute